# How is ejabberd external auth supposed to work?

Tags: php, authentication, ejabberd

If I use my custom PHP script as `auth_method: external`, all `isuser` and `auth` calls are redirected to my script, right? So if whatever process (ejabberdctl, web dashboard, ejabberdctl) tries to register or login, it will be redirected to my script.

I tried to register users via API or ejabberdctl `register`. But then I noticed that also those calls are redirected to my script, via `tryregister`. And even if I respond with 1, the users don't end up as registered users in ejabberd. (I would expect that I can do my custom bit, but they would also end up in ejabberd.)

But I can still put vcard information for those users in ejabberd! And retrieve that. So, using my external auth:

- I can not register users in ejabberd only "on my side" with the custom script,
- They will not appear in `registered_users` response. Only previously added users (using `auth_method: internal`) are in that response.
- I *can* put vcard data in ejabberd using `set_vcard` etc. API calls.
- And get those values back with `get_vcard` using `host`, `user` and vcard field `name`.

If the users are not registered in ejabberd, how come I can still set and get vcard data?? And what's the use of this if I cannot retrieve a list of users / vcard holders / however I should call them (they are not "registered users")?

Thanks in advance.